# Windows weird Browsing behaviour

Tags: networking, windows-10

I tried to visit a site on my Windows 10 browser (tried Chrome, IE, FF) the site shows a different content (totally different site) like how you change it from etc/Hosts.

I tried to debug what's going on, to ping {site}.com (shows a different site IP), i tried the Safe Mode and got the same result, however when i tried to change the Internet i am using (ISP) it showed the correct site, and when i used the old internet it showed a weird site, is this kind of behavior an ISP related or windows caching ips/sites and can this be fixed within my reach or is it the ISP who's responsible for this ?

-- EDIT

Oh, by the OLD internet i mean my Phone's 3G internet, new Internet is my Home internet.

**the actual weird thing is that on my phone's browser (chrome, android) it shows the correct site! but not on Windows. So using the very same internet on Phone and Windows i get different sites (android shows the correct one, windows shows the weird one, different ip, and on the Home Internet both are correct**

so it's something in my windows i believe.

*and by 'different site' i mean it's showing y.com not x.com, as if you visit facebook.com but you get youtube.com content.*

Comment: Probably the isp (dns out of date). Try changing your dns servers to the google servers (8.8.8.8 and/or 8.8.4.4)

Comment: Website shows some different views and contents in different browser depending on their useragent. May you post your website? Did you write it correctly in browser?

Comment: @DavidPostill read the part i added, that's what actually made me confused.

Comment: If it works on your new internet why are you worrying about it?

Comment: @DavidPostill cuz i use my phone's internet all the time, i need to for work, the big question is why windows on my phone's internet is hitting a different site ip with the same domain name, while on my phone's browser it's showing the correct site.

Comment: @DavidPostill same like changing /etc/Hosts in windows, same behavior but Hosts is not changed i checked that.

Comment: @DavidPostill and Even if it has been changed, why on my Home's internet it's showing the correct site. as if windows is checking if the Internet is A, shows him site X.com as Y.com and if Internet is B show him site Y.com (the correct site)

Comment: @DavidPostill changing the DNS to google's worked. still weird behavior anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by @DavidPostil comment, manually changing the network dns to google's DNS and reverting back to Automatic fixed the issue.

i still don't understand why, the best explanation is windows caching stuff, but running ipconfig /flushdns did not fix it.

anyway, thanks!

Comment: "i still don't understand why" the  DNS of one of your ISPs is broken.

Comment: @DavidPostill but if it's really broken it wouldn't work on my phone's browser, it would stop working on both. so it has something to do with windows caching and not browser caching cuz i tried 3 browsers with same results, only refreshing my dns on windows as you suggested solved it.